# Can multiprocessing.Queue replace Manager.list() in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I am working on a project where I am using multiprocessing and trying to achieve the minimal time. (I have tested that my one process takes around 4secs and if there are 8 processes working in parallel they should take around the same time or lets say around 6 to 7secs at max.

In the list of arguments, A Manager.List() (lets call it main_list) is a common argument that is passed to each process to append a list in the **main_list** after processing a txt file ( includes conversions, transformations and multiplications of hex data).

Same procedure is followed in all 8 processes.

By using Manager.List(), it was taking around 22 secs. I wanted a way around so I could reduce this time. Now, I am using Queue to achieve my goal but it seems like that the queue will not be effective for this method?

```
def square(x, q):
    q.put((x,x*x))
if __name__=='__main__':
    qout = mp.Queue()
    processes=[]
    t1=time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(10):
        p = mp.Process(target=square, args=(i, qout))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    unsorted_result = [qout.get() for p in processes]
    result = [t[1] for t in sorted(unsorted_result)]
    t2=time.perf_counter()
    print(t2-t1)
    print(result)

OUTPUT
0.7646916
```

I want to be sure if i can consider using Queue this way instead of Manager.list() to reduce this time.

I am sorry for not sharing the actual code.

Comment: I confess that I don't understand your timings. You say that one process takes 4 seconds to run but when you have 8 processes working in parallel they *should take around the same time* or even longer (6 or 7 seconds). I am sure you know what you mean, but I don't because 8 processes *might* take more time but *should* take less time or else there is no point to using multiprocessing. Anyway, why don't you just try the Queue? Or better yet, use `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map` which internally has a queue but relieves you from doing explicit sorting and it returns a list of results.

Comment: @Booboo Yes that's the point. the processes are working in parallel so they should be completed in same time or little bit longer.
Yes i am using pool for this purpose. Anyways, Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to your question. This would be the solution using a multiprocessing pool with method `map`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def square(x):
    return x * x

if __name__=='__main__':
    # Create a pool with 10 processes:
    pool = Pool(10)
    result = pool.map(square, range(10))
    print(result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```None
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

The managed list that you were using is represented by a proxy object. Every `append` operation you do on that list results in a message being sent to a thread running in a process started by the `multiprocessing.SyncManager` instance that was created when you presumably called `multiprocessing.Manager()`. It is in that process where the actual list resides. So managed lists are generally not the most efficient solution available.

Comment: if I am sending a common parameter to each of the processes using pool, does it create copies of that parameter for each process or it tries to access the same? I mean if it does try to access the same variable, it would add delay to the task. Correct me if am wrong pls.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you were using `map`, for example, and needed to send an *additional* argument for each call with the same value, then you would use the `functools.partial` function to pass that additional fixed argument to each invocation of your worker function. The only common argument you were passing in your code was `qout`, which is no longer used in my code; your `i` value is not common because its value is changing for each call and is passed implicitly in multiprocessing by being written to an internal queue. What do you really mean by a "common" parameter?