# Return multiprocessing results, Queue or manager.list?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Note: this question is different from [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545746/can-multiprocessing-queue-replace-manager-list-in-python), notably in when the jobs are dispatched to the workers and when the results are gathered.

So I have this code:

```
    mp_jobqueue = MP.Queue()
    mp_mgr = MP.Manager()
    mp_state = mp_mgr.dict()
    mp_faileds = mp_mgr.list()

    # the processing in process_data_worker is very CPU-intensive,
    # thus totally not suitable for async.
    workers: List[MP.Process] = []
    for ident in range(0, WORKER_COUNT):
        print(ident, end=" ", flush=True)
        mp_state[ident] = None
        w = MP.Process(
            target=process_data_worker,
            args=(mp_jobqueue, mp_state, mp_faileds),
        )
        w.start()
        workers.append(w)

    # fetch_data asynchronously fetches chunks of data,
    # each chunk will be directly fed into the job queue to be processed
    # by the workers
    asyncio.run(fetch_data(mp_jobqueue))

    # when we reach here, all data-fetching should have been finished
    # and submitted to the workers' job queue

    # wait until mp_jobqueue is empty AND all workers are IDLE
    safed_workers = 0
    while not mp_jobqueue.is_empty() or safed_workers < WORKER_COUNT:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        safed_workers = sum(1 for state in mp_state.values() if state == "IDLE")

    # gather failed results
    faileds = list(mp_faileds)

    # close manager first to prevent GetOverlappedResult error
    mp_mgr.shutdown()
    mp_mgr.join()

    # disband the workers
    [mp_jobqueue.put("DIE") for _ in workers]
    time.sleep(1.0)
    mp_jobqueue.close()
    [w.join() for w in workers]
```

So as you can see, I cannot use `pool.map()` to gather the "faileds".

This got me thinking, though:

Will it be better (performance-wise) to use another Queue for `mp_faileds` instead of a list like it is now? Because I only need an object that can handle "add into bag" and "take out from bag until bag is empty".

**Edit:** Just found out about `multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue`. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8463008/149900), notably [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71335908/149900), seems to hint that `SimpleQueue` might be even faster. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Well as I am sure you know, a Queue and a list are different data structures with different properties and use cases.  It seems that you already have a working program that uses a list.  So what would you hope to gain by switching to a Queue?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @PaulCornelius yes I understand, I'll have to change how the results get added to the 'collecting bag', and how the main program retrieves the contents of the bag. I just want to make the process of "workers submitting results of their work" to be more efficient, as I don't really need the full abilities of the list (indexing, etc.) I just need an MP data structure that supports "adding into" and "popping from".